# Back to back Pipes into a Command

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

Is there a way to pipe back to back values into a command? e.g. If I can `command.pl` and want to pipe in `response`, then `y` to confirm (because it doesn't have a way to auto confirm)?

I've tried `echo "y" | echo "response" | ./command.pl` but it doesn't work because the ordering of the pipe is from left to right. In essence, I need to run the one pipe first, then pipe the next command after that. Is there a trick with parentheses or quotes or something else?

Comment: What I think you are looking for is a program called `expect`

Comment: Related: [How can I get a Perl script to read input from both STDIN and command line arguments?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171182/how-can-i-get-a-perl-script-to-read-input-from-both-stdin-and-command-line-argum)

Comment: `./command.pl <<<$'y\nresponse'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried grouping your two answers in a single `echo` separated by a newline?

```
echo -e "response\ny" | ./command.pl
```

Note the `-e` flag is necessary with `bash` to enable interpretation of backslash escapes (unless `bash` is in Unix conformance mode).

Or more portably:

```
echo 'response
y' | ./command.pl
```

Or:

```
printf 'response\ny\n' | ./command.pl
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' response y | ./command.pl
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, but the problem with your initial command was that `echo` doesn't take any input via its STDIN. The output of the command `echo "y"` never reached `./command.pl`.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest solution is to combine the two echo commands.

```
echo $'y\nresponse' | ./command.pl
```

Writing a string with single quotes and a `$` in front tells bash to interpret escape sequences like `\n`.

If the commands you were piping were more complicated, you could group them with curly braces.

```
{ echo y; echo response; } | ./command.pl
```

Parentheses would also work, though they'd create an unnecessary extra sub-shell (a minor inefficiency).

```
(echo y; echo response) | ./command.pl
```

Another option is process substitution.

```
./command.pl < <(echo y; echo response)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells):

```
./command.pl <<END
response
y
END
```

Answer (score 4):

I put the commands into a file then catted the file into the command and that worked.

`cat blah.txt | ./command`

When I came back, I noticed user43791's response, so will accept that as the answer which looks to be the same thing I did, but more succinct.

Comment: Glad my answer fits your need! :) Btw, your command could be rewritten like so : `./command < blah.txt` (redirect stdin from the file). This would be much more efficient since it saves you a process (cat) and a pipe.

Comment: @user43791 is right, and you can even do the following (makes it more like the cat you usually use) : `<blah.txt ./command`